# How to access integer value(e.g serverport or connection poolSize) from properties file in Spiring MVC application appliactionContext.xml file

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, properties-file

I have define the configuration like this in the applicationContext.xml

```
<beans:property name="host" value="${mail.server.host}" />
<beans:property name="port" value="25" />
<beans:property name="protocol"  value="${mail.server.protocol}"  />
```

when I am putting the following line in the file than it throws an number format exception. The upper code is working fine its just throwing an exception on port value.

```
<beans:property name="port" value="${mail.server.port}" />
```

Comment: Post the full exception stack trace. What is the value of `mail.server.port` in your properties?

Comment: Did you configure the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`? How do you include the properties file? And what is the content of your properties file?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the value of mail.server.port=587

Comment: @fateddy I am loading the properties file from classpath the content of the properties file are 
mail.server.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.server.protocol=smtp
mail.server.port=587

Comment: Did you configure the propertyplaceholderconfigurer?

Comment: yes I configure the property placeholder it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configure the property placeholder for integer values like server port etc.
after configuring the placeholder we can use in the example below.

```
<!-- Read configuration properties -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:configuration.properties"/>

<property name="host" value="${mail.server.host}" />
<property name="port" value="${mail.server.port}" />
<property name="protocol" value="${mail.server.protocol}" />
<property name="username" value="${mail.server.username}" />
<property name="password" value="${mail.server.password}" />
```